# Unable to type in UITextfield after leaving view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have a view that has a `UIScrollView` with many `UITextField` controls. If after typing in any of the `UItextField` controls, I click somewhere else and then navigate to another view, once I return to the same view I can no longer type in the `UITextField`.

I also have this code for each of the `UITextField` controls on the view.

```
//self.QuestionAnswer = UITextField - This is the control with the issues.
[self.QuestionAnswer addTarget:self action:@selector(SaveQuestionAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
[self.QuestionAnswer addTarget:self action:@selector(SaveQuestionAnswer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];


//sender = self.QuestionAnswer - This control is of type UITextField.
-(IBAction)SaveQuestionAnswer:(id)sender
//some code here
   [control resignFirstResponder];
//some code here
}
```

I also verified that `[control resignFirstResponder]` is getting executed when losing focus on the `UITextField`.

Comment: what is "control" here???what is "QuestionAnswer"?

Comment: When you return back to this view, viewWillAppear: method will called. Check are you disabling the textField in that method.

Comment: control likely == sender, QuestionAnswer likey == IBOutlet to TextField.

Comment: [self.QuestionAnswer becomeFirstResponder] in viewDidAppear :)

Comment: R.A I have added a couple of comments to describe what "Control" and "QuestionAnswer" are. It is just like Daij Djan explained.

Comment: I made sure that I am not disabling any UITextFieldControls.

Comment: Daij Djan,I have tried to add [self.QuestionAnswer becomeFirstResponder] on viewDudAppear and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. All of my controllers inherit from a base controller. Inside this base controller I have methods that handle all the navigation for my app.

Added these two methods to my base class. If you don't have a base class you can add this your controller. This will cycle through all the controls on the view and release first responder.

```
-(void)StartReleaseAllFirstResponders
{
    for(UIView *Item in [self.view subviews]) {
        [self ReleaseAllFirstResponders:Item];
    }
}

-(void)ReleaseAllFirstResponders:(UIView*)OriginItem
{
    for(UIView *Item in [OriginItem subviews]) {
        [Item resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [OriginItem resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This is an example of the implementation.

```
-(void)Navigate_Home
{
    [self StartReleaseAllFirstResponders]; //Making sure we release all first responders
    HomeController *GoToView= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeController"];
    GoToView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:GoToView animated:YES completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```